# onsen react navigator pushpage overwrites last page

Tags: reactjs, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

In a project, my intention is to use only one Navigator element to handle all page navigation.

There is one singleton `appState` all over the code, and `navigator` is member of that, it gets initialized by the outermost `App` component.

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <App/>,
   document.getElementById('app')
 );
```

The navigator is initiated by:

```
initialRoute = {
  component: LoginPage,
  props: {
}};
```

and

```
<Ons.Navigator
  initialRoute={this.initialRoute}
  renderPage={this.renderPage.bind(this)}
/>
```

and

```
renderPage(route: Route, navigator: typeof Ons.Navigator) {
  const props: any = route.props || {};
  if (appState.navigator == null) {
    appState.navigator = navigator;
  }
  props.navigator = appState.navigator;
  return React.createElement(route.component, route.props);
}
```

correctly with `initialRoute`. When I call `pushPage(newRoute)`, the newRoute is apparently added, when checked at the time of addition. That is, I get the following right after pushing `newRoute`:

```
LoginPage
HomePage
```

However, a subsequent call to `pushPage(someOtherRoute)` yields

```
LoginPage
SomeOtherRouteComponent
```

I would expect

```
LoginPage
HomePage
SomeOtherRouteComponent
```

I have verified that there is no issue with synchronization etc, when I push the route object to an aside list, I get everything without any loss. But just `pushPage` is not working as I expect.

Any ideas, or missing something obvious? The snippets are TS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that any error during page load is caught by `Navigator`, and that causes the page to be not added into routes (but the page is still navigated to).

I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/OnsenUI/react-onsenui/issues/141) on github with a workaround. An alternative workaround is to make sure that there are no JS errors during page load, which may not be 100% the case given 3rd party modules are present.